# How do you get the Duke to reappear?

Tags: castleville

The Duke disappearance bug in CastleVille seems to be a very prevalent one. Is there a way to make the Duke reappear, or at least get his quests back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a known issue. They are working on a game-wide fix, but in the meantime, they are trying to manually fix this for each individual user, so it is taking them a while.

From [this forum](http://forums.zynga.com/showthread.php?p=10707847#post10707847):

> Originally Posted by Ziffer   Last Update: 12/20
>
> Description:
>
> Since 11/23, some players have reported losing the Duke's Quest Line
>   after going OOS and are unable to restart the Quest Line to finish it.
>
> Status: The CastleVille Team is actively investigating and addressing.
>
> Workaround: Please contact Customer Support for a fix.
>
> Link to bug report thread:
>   [here](http://forums.zynga.com/showthread.php?t=1239143)

Here are some things [that they suggest trying](http://forums.zynga.com/showthread.php?t=1239143):

> Known Issue: http://forums.zynga.com/showthread.php?t=1243568
>
> Getting your game to work might be just a few steps away. Before
>   posting a bug report, try out these trouble shooting tips.
>
> If you have done all of these and still need to post your bug report
>   please provide the following, whether you create a new thread or post
>   in an existing one.
>
> - Have you tried clearing your cache and reloading the game?
> - Have you tried all the other troubleshooting steps listed in [this guide](http://forums.zynga.com/showthread.php?t=1219669)? Including restarting your computer?
> - Please provide your browser and version
> - Please provide your operating system and version
> - Please provide your flash version.
> - Are you receiving any errors when you try loading the game? If so you could you please post a screenshot of that error?
> - Please describe the issue. If you are receiving an error please provide as much information as possible regarding what you were trying
>     to do in the game right before it happened.
> - If possible, please provide your facebook user ID (please do not post anyone else's user ID, as that would violate the forum Rules of
>     Conduct